# UPDATE doesn´t work properly (updates only a few rows) (XML to MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, xml, api

So, i have a XML Api from thetvdb.com

Resources:
Here you have a little extract out of the XML API: http://pastebin.com/0UgMU6wZ

My Database:

[image]

My script to update the Database:

```
include('config.php');
$series = simplexml_load_file("breakingbad.xml");

for ($episode = 0; $episode <= 61; $episode++) {
    $title = $series->Episode[$episode]->EpisodeName;
}

$episodenumber = $series->Episode[$episode]->Combined_episodenumber;
$season = $series->Episode[$episode]->Combined_season;
$desc = $series->Episode[$episode]->Overview;
echo "$title... $season...$episodenumber...$desc<br>";

mysql_query("
    UPDATE series
    SET episodename = '$title', description = '$desc'
    WHERE tvshow='breakingbad' AND season = '$season' AND episode = '$episodenumber'");
}
```

As you can see in the database pic it updates several rows but not all of them.

To check if $title, $episodenumber etc. is not empty i made the echo in the script..

Everthing works fine:

[image]

but it doesn´t update all of them

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. Chances are, you are injecting characters that SQL does not agree with. You will need to escape your values.

Comment: Obligatory [MySQL is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) comment, please use MySQLi or the PDO instead, also read about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) since your code is vunerable to it.

Comment: doesnt give me an error, sql is

Comment: Your values contains apostrophes which SQL will complain about. That alone will/should throw an error. [**Use `mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements). That should most likely fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
    $title = mysql_escape_string($series->Episode[$episode]->EpisodeName);
    $episodenumber = mysql_escape_string($series->Episode[$episode]->Combined_episodenumber);
    $season = mysql_escape_string($series->Episode[$episode]->Combined_season);
    $desc = mysql_escape_string($series->Episode[$episode]->Overview);
```

Comment: Please explain how and why this code should work

Comment: Variables in sql query must be quoted, to prevent sql injection.

Comment: sql injection is in this case not important, because its not an open script, its just for automation, will try your code hold on :) EDIT: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_quote()

Comment: Sorry, change mysql_quote to mysql_escape_string.

Comment: It worked thanks!!!! Edit the code in your first post so ppl won´t get irritated :)